# Как создать POST запрос?

Tags: python, requests, post

Всем добрый день. Извиняюсь за довольно глупый вопрос. Но я не могу сделать адекватный пост запрос, чтобы достать данные  с апи. Так выглядит payload:

```
c_id: 636
g_id: 917
sch_id: 
sch_good_id: 
test_id: 
store: msk-0_1721_1
sort: +p6984+1146+1147+6994
page: all
thumbnail_view: 2
spoiler: 
fts: 
isManualShop: 0
tag: 
filter_type: 
command: get_goods
acparams: true
fts_stats: true
sign: ac1c2d15c737ba6c4ed59bd20f2b6858
```

Url по которому нужно сделать запрос : https://www.nix.ru/lib/fast_search.php.
Заранее благодарю за помощь!!!

Comment: Попробуйте капнуть в сторону библиотеки `requests` для python

Comment: для дебага запроса можно использовать `http.client`

Comment: Я дал ответ, он вас устраивает?